# CORS in OAuth: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, cors, preflight

So I'm trying to implement the OAuth 2 flow, while my webapp is the server that give away authorization code/access token.

Cors error happens when sending the code back to third-party website(zapier in this case):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://zapier.com/dashboard/auth/oauth/return/App505CLIAPI/?code=somecode&state=somestate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myurl' is therefore not allowed access.

If I manually open a new tab, paste that zapier uri, everything works perfectly.

Seems like a typical CORS issue, but none the popular solutions works for me:

1. Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`: I'm using this [oauth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize)
   library, and sending reponse to preflight seems also part of the
   library. So I cannot add header.
2. Using [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors): Have tried `app.use(cors())` and `app.options('*',
   cors())` which should apply to all routes, but simply not working.

My webapp sits on a node express server, in front of which there's an nginx proxy server.

Any idea where the problem might be is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that error message indicates isn’t caused by the app code running at `https://myurl/`. Instead it’s just that `https://zapier.com/dashboard/auth/…` doesn’t seem to support CORS.

Specifically, the response from that `https://zapier.com/dashboard/auth/…` URL doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, so your browser won’t let your frontend JavaScript code access the response.

It seems like that is all intentional on the part of Zapier—they don’t intend for that auth endpoint to be accessed from frontend AJAX/XHR/Fetch code running in a browser. Instead I guess it’s intended that you only access that auth endpoint from your backend code. Or something.

Anyway there is no way from your side that you can fix the fact the response from that Zapier API endpoint doesn’t include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

And as long as it doesn’t include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, your browser blocks your frontend code from being able to get to the response—and there’s no way to get your browser to behave otherwise as long as your frontend code is trying to hit that API endpoint directly.

So the only solution is to not hit that API endpoint directly from your frontend code but to instead either set up a proxy and change your frontend code to make the request through that, or else just handle it in some other way in your existing backend code, as mentioned above.

The answer at [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707) gives some details on how you can set up a special CORS proxy, if you want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with external API provider. The error pointed to preflight check error. But, when I monitored network in browser dev tools, Options call was returning 200 status.

"they don’t intend for that auth endpoint to be accessed from frontend AJAX/XHR/Fetch code running in a browser" this line by sideshowbarker is the correct assessment. I moved the code to my API & it worked well.